# Как обработать событие динамически созданного компонента?

Tags: delphi

Есть некоторое количество динамически созданных компонентов Image, которые можно перемещать по форме следующим кодом:

```
procedure TForm1.Image1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
if ToMove then
  with (Sender as TImage) do
    begin
    Left:=TImage(Sender).Left+(x-x2);
    Top:=TImage(Sender).Top+(y-y2);
    end;
end;
```

Вопрос: А как изменить позицию выделенного Image, посредством использования процедуры:

```
procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
```

Пробовал сделать что-то вроде этого:

```
procedure up(Sender: TObject);
begin
if Sender is TImage then (Sender as TImage).Top:=(Sender as TImage).Top-10;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
if (key=VK_UP) then up(TImage);
end;
```

Но не получилось, ошибка: Incompatible types: 'TObject' and 'Class reference'

**UPD:** Эта проблема устранена, теперь возникла новая: процедура применяется к последнему добавленному Image. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как применить процедуру к Image по которому был совершен клик? Пробовал что-то делать с Tag, но ничего не вышло.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам в процедуру `up` нужно передать созданный вами динамический **объект**, т.е. `Image1`, судя по наименованию метода.

В приведенном же коде, вы пытаетесь передать в эту процедуру **класс**, а не объект. Вы наверно не очень чётко понимаете разницу между классом и объектом, поэтому и допустили такую ошибку. Объект - экземпляр класса и вы можете создать несколько объектов одного и того же класса.

Чтобы навести порядок в голове и разложить всё по полочкам, рекомендую вдумчиво ознакомиться с заметкой: [Delphi. Урок 18. Классы и объекты](http://cybern.ru/delphi-objects-classes.html)

А вот тут: [Визуальные компоненты VCL и ООП](http://www.snkey.net/books/delphi/ch2-2.html) подробно расписано, что же такое **компонент**:

> Если же говорить именно о компонентах, а не о каких-то абстрактных классах, то их прародителем является класс TComponent, являющийся прямым потомком класса TPersistent. Именно происходящие от TComponent классы являются компонентами Delphi, в том числе теми, что отображаются на палитре компонент.

Т.е. это обычный **класс**, за исключением того, что он наследуется не от `TObject`, а от `TComponent`. И ввиду этого обстоятельства, не может быть "динамически созданного компонента", как звучит в вашем вопросе. Всё что создано - **объект**.

Comment: Большое спасибо, теперь процедура работает. Но только с последним созданным Image. Не подскажите как быть?

Comment: Она работает с тем Image, который вы ей передаёте.

Comment: Передаю Image, имя которого изменяется по мере загрузки новых Image следующим образом:
`nIm.Picture:=Image1.Picture;
nIm.name:='Image_'+inttostr(n);
inc(n);
nIm.Picture.LoadFromFile(FileName);`

Comment: По идее нужно применять процедуру к Image по которому был произведен клик. Ума не приложу как это реализовать.

Comment: @YoungPadawan В `Image` есть событие - `onClick`, если его переопределить и записать текущий объект как последний выделенный, тогда можно воспользоваться им в дальнейшем для перемещения.

Comment: @androschuk Да, это я и пытался сделать, результат - ноль. Возможно я что-то делаю не так. Буду очень благодарен если кто-нибудь поделится кодом, разрушающим этот камень преткновения.

Answer (score 1):

В целом как я и писал нужно по `onClick` запоминаем элемент, по `FormKeyUp` перемещаем его.

1. Для формы устанавливаем свойство `KeyPreview = True`. Для того чтобы события нажатия клавиш сперва пересылались форме, а потом управляемому компоненту.
2. Немного кода:

Подключаем модули, если их нет для кнопки, картинки и Generic списка.

```
uses
 ...ExtCtrls, StdCtrls, Generics.Collections;
```

Определяем тип `TMoveDirection` с направлением движения:

```
type
  TMoveDirection = (mdUp, mdDown, mdLeft, mdRight);

TMainForm = class(TForm)
  ...
private
  FImages : TObjectList<TImage>; //Список с картинками
  FLastSelected : TImage;  //Последний выделенный элемент
  procedure ImageClickEvent(Sender: TObject);
  procedure Move(ADirection: TMoveDirection; AControl: TControl);
end;

...
implementation
```

Процедура перемещения Control'a с указанием направления

```
procedure TMainForm.Move(ADirection : TMoveDirection; AControl : TControl);
const
  Step  = 5;
begin
   if not Assigned(AControl) Then
     exit;

   case ADirection of
     mdUp: AControl.Top := AControl.Top - Step;
     mdDown: AControl.Top := AControl.Top + Step;
     mdLeft: AControl.Left := AControl.Left - Step;
     mdRight: AControl.Left := AControl.Left + Step;
   end;
 end;
```

Событие ImageClickEvent которое отрабатывает при клике мышкой

```
 procedure TMainForm.ImageClickEvent(Sender: TObject);
 begin
   if Sender is TImage then
   begin
     FLastSelected := (Sender as TImage);
   end;
 end;
```

Мой алгоритм создания и построения элементов. Кстати `img.Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromFile('ball_blue.bmp');` служит для отображения картинки в `TImage`. Никакой нагрузки не несет.

```
procedure TMainForm.btnBuildClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  img : TImage;
  I: Integer;
  LeftPos : Integer;
const
  LeftIdent = 10;
  TopIdent = 40;
  ImageSize = 64;
  MaxImageCount = 5;
begin
  FImages.Clear;

  // Создание MaxImageCount элементов
  for I := 0 to MaxImageCount do
  begin
    img := TImage.Create(Nil);
    img.Height := ImageSize;
    img.Width := ImageSize;
    img.OnClick := ImageClickEvent;
    img.Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromFile('ball_blue.bmp'); 
    FImages.Add(img);
  end;

  //Построение на форме
  LeftPos := LeftIdent;

  for I := 0 to FImages.Count - 1 do
  begin
    LeftPos := img.Width * I + LeftIdent * I;

     img := FImages.Items[I];
     img.Left := LeftPos;
     img.Top := TopIdent;
     img.Parent := Self;
  end;
end;
```

Событие `FormKeyUp`, которое отрабатывает при клике любой клавишей (Не забываем об `KeyPreview = True` для формы).

```
procedure TMainForm.FormKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if Key = VK_UP then
    Move(mdUp, FLastSelected)
  else
  if Key = VK_DOWN then
    Move(mdDown, FLastSelected)
  else
  if Key = VK_LEFT then
    Move(mdLeft, FLastSelected)
  else
  if Key = VK_RIGHT then
    Move(mdRight, FLastSelected)
end;
```

Создание и уничтожение списка с созданными объектами.

```
procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FImages := TObjectList<TImage>.Create;
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
    FreeAndNil(FImages);
end;
```

Код ни на что не претендует, простая реализация задачи. Создавайте отдельные классы, не используйте глобальные переменные....
Придет время и я сделаю заметку на эту тему у себя в [блоге](http://mirsovetov.net/blog)

Comment: Благодарю за очень подробный ответ. Вы мой спаситель. Я чуть не рехнулся решая данную задачу своими способами.